# How can I disable automatic creation of sandbox directories without disabling sandboxing in a OS X app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, micro-optimization, appstore-sandbox

Sandboxing prevents the app from making unwanted changes to the system or files, so as such, only sandboxed apps may be published to App Store. So on launch, a [sandbox container directory is created](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-the-macos-app-sandbox/) in at least `~/Library/Containers` and `~/Library/Application Scripts`.

> The first time the user launches your sandboxed app, the system creates its container — a folder in ~/Library/Containers that your app has exclusive read-write access to.

How can I disable this behavior while keeping the application sandboxed?

If my application a simple tool that does not use the sandbox container and/or does not support Scripts, **these extraneous directories are bloat**. If I disable app sandbox, the creation of these directories is disabled, but App Store will not accept the app, and there is no protection from unwanted filesystem changes.

No code is provided because the issue is hidden in the Apple framework code that creates these directories upon launching a sandboxed app. A newly-created Application project in Xcode is already a minimal reproducible example. At what point in the application launch is are the sandbox directories created, and how can I override it with no-ops?

Comment: You are going to fight the framework. Don't.

Comment: @vadian But is there a way?

Comment: Minimal usage is under 2K.  Those "extraneous directories" are part of the sandbox.  You are fighting a losing battle.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's standard that those folders are created. They do not harm anything nor anybody.